# When does a dart program finishes executing?

Tags: dart

Could someone please explain why the below program is not exiting after executing the last statement i.e. print(....) but it keeps running until the Future completes?

```
void main() {
  Future.delayed(
    const Duration(seconds: 3),
    () => 100,
  );
  print('Waiting for a value...');
}
```

Comment: If you want to to exit right away you should use: [exit](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-io/exit.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart does have an Event queue so the Dart VM only stops when the main loop is done, the Event queue are empty and all timers has been executed. Since `Future.delayed` spawns an internal timer the Dart VM will wait for the timer to be executed before the Dart VM stops.

The timer ends up spawning a new task on the event queue which try gets the result of the future. But since nobody are waiting for that result the Dart VM will then stops after this.